# Unable to add a tmap title in interactive viewing mode

Tags: r, tmap

I am using `tmap` on RStudio 1.4.1103.

When I try to add a title to my map using the `tm_layout()` function call, I am able to see the title in plotting mode, but when I switch to interactive viewing mode, the title disappears.

Please find below a minimal reproducible code with the resulting output map:

```r
library(tmap)

data("World")

ttm()

tm_shape(World) + tm_polygons("HPI") + tm_layout(title="Hello World!")
```

[image: code output example]

Answer (score 0):

Update: It appears this is an issue in the most recent version of tmap, as documented [here](https://github.com/mtennekes/tmap/issues/524).

Comment: The link is not longer active